# iOS Phonegap App with Facebook login / share

Tags: ios, facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova

My app has some facebook javascript code which prompts a user to facebook URLS, and then can't find it's way back to my app is there a way to fix this?

I saw there is a childbrowser plugin, but is there any other options?

Comment: According to a post I read online I can use the iOS SDK with my phonegap build, and use javascript SDK calls from within the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of sums up what I was trying to do.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin#add-the-facebook-ios-and-javascript-sdk